# Flatten nested array in Angular to query similar to linq

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am building an Angular tree component using cdk-tree and want to query for the single selected node however because the array is nested I can't easily do this with .filter.

The single object structure I have is as below:

```
export class MyTreeNode {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    selected?: boolean;
    children?: MyTreeNode[];
}
```

I have an array of these to build the tree, if I query using something like .filter, than only the top level is returned however I want to be able to query the child nodes too.

My thinking is if I flatten the array I can use .filter to query all data however is this the most sensible way?

Cheers!

Comment: do you have an example of `linq`?

Comment: Please provide some sample data for the input, expected output and a clear criteria on how you want to filter to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are working with a tree-like structure, I would use a function that operates on trees, either recursively or iteratively, for example

```
function searchNodeById(tree: MyTreeNode, id: string): MyTreeNode {
  const stack: MyTreeNode[] = [];
  let node: MyTreeNode;
  stack.push(tree);
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    node = stack.pop();
    if (node.id === id) return node;
    if (node.children) stack.push(...node.children);
  }
}
```

---

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/QuintessentialPuzzledCustomers)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks a lot! Neat little solution